# How to determine rendered size of graphics in Image Control

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics

I have an Image control set for Uniform stretch. It is wider than tall (landscape). I am putting a graphic (source) in it that is taller than wide (portrait). This means that the top and bottom of the graphic match the top and bottom of the Image control and there is 'dead space' on either side of the graphic. Got the picture? (pun intended)

At this point I zoom in and out of the graphic using a Matrix.ScaleAtPrepend on the Image control and pan using Matrix.OffsetX and OffsetY.  Works great.

Now I would like to click on the panned/zoomed graphic and get the pixel coordinates of my click relative to the graphic and not relative to the Image control.

How might I do that?

Comment: You may divide the Image control's `ActualWidth` by the the `Width` of its `Source` to get the scaling factor that results from the uniform stretch. Then multiply that with the Matrix scale factor. You might also just set Stretch to None and only apply an appropriate Matrix transform.

Comment: So you're saying I need to keep track of the accumulated scaling rather than being able to read something directly from the control or graphic?

Comment: No, you can do that calculation at any time. All three values are available from the objects you're dealing with.

Comment: HI @ Daveecove - Were you able to do this ? I am myself stuck into the same problem ! Any help would be highly appreciated